# Why is there a と in front of 別?

Tags: particle-と

I found this sentence in a workbook:

> それとこれ**と**は別でしょう。

My translation of this sentence is:

> As for that and this, they are different.

What is the significance of the second と? How is the sentence translated with it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure it's a duplicate. It might just be that the asker doesn't know that 別 takes と

Comment: @oals but 別 doesn't take と... (それとこれは別でしょう would be perfectly fine!)

Comment: @broccoliforest Could それとこれとは別 mean "[this other thing] is different from that and that [two things]"?

Comment: @Earthliŋ Oh, that's possible (but practically we say それ（とか／や）これ（とか）とは別 in that situation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally, と was used after each word in a list. From [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A8-579147):

> いくつかの事柄を列挙する意を表す。「君―ぼく―の仲」
>   [補説] **並立する語ごとに「と」を用いるのが本来の用法**であるが、現代語ではいちばんあとにくる「と」を省略するのが普通となっている。

The last と in a list is usually omitted at least in modern Japanese. In this sentence, you can safely omit the second と, but explicitly putting the second と emphasizes that these two (それ and これ) are contrasted. `AとBと` is still common in formal or complex sentences.

See: [「X」と「Y」と - how does the second と affect the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30969/5010)