# Meaning of と in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-と

In a short story I'm reading (or trying to) I found this sentence:

> 屋上の手すりから、ひらひらと風になびくタータンチェックのひだスカート**と**、そこからにょっきりと生えた二本の脚**と**が見えた

I think the general meaning is the character saw from the rooftop's handrail someone's legs protuding from her skirt fluttering in the wind, but I can't understand what the two `と` in bold means, and how would the sentence's meaning be different without them.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30969/5010

Comment: So it'd be something like "I saw skirt fluttering in the wind **and** two legs protuding from there [the skirt]", with `そこから` being "from the skirt"?

Comment: Yes. Do you mind if this is marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Go ahead, no problem.